# Close the form on certain hours of the day

Tags: delphi

I would like my form to close when the time is 06:00, 12:00 and 24:00.
But before it closes I would like to display a progress bar showing
how much time is remaining before the form closes (When the progress
bar reaches 100% - the form closes). How can I do this?

Edit:
I was doing this:

```
procedure TMainForm.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
Timer1.Enabled := False;
 AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[4].Progress.Position := AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[4].Progress.Position +1;
 if AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[4].Progress.Position = 100 then begin
 MainForm.Close;
 end;
 Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;
```

So what I need is perhaps another timer which would detect the time of the day and fire on designated time the progress bar (Timer1.Enabled := True;). How do you detect the right time in code?

Comment: Put a timer and a progress bar. In timer's interval calculate the remaining time and update the progress bar accordingly. When you reach 100%, close.

Comment: I am unsure how to do this. Do you need 2 timers? One to detect time and another to manipulate the progress bar ?

Comment: What is the horizontal time scale of the bar?

Comment: about a minute and a half ...

Comment: I think the appropriate question you should be asking is "How to make a progress bar count down to a certain time?" Closing your form at that time would be peanuts, as long as you can get the progress bar down. All you need is one timer.

Comment: @Jerry Can you provide some code example ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you investigate Waitable timers.  These can be set to set to fire after a specific period of time (like a regular TTimer) or at a specified time of day, which is exactly what you need in this case.

In your form create/show event, create a waitable timer and set it to the required time that you wish it to 'fire' (it will be only one of your candidate close times, i.e the next one to occur after the current time).  In your case I believe you mentioned the countdown starts 90 seconds before the close time, so this is your "due time" for the waitable timer (next T - 90 secs).

The due time you set must be specified in **FILETIME** and must be in UTC, not local time.  This is fiddly, but not especially difficult.

Calculate the next auto close time, less 90 seconds.  Then use **DateTimeToSystemTime(localTDateTime, localSYSTEMTIME)** to the resulting **TDateTime** value in a **SYSTEMTIME** representation which you can then pass to [TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/windows/desktop/ms725485(v=vs.85).aspx) to convert to a UTC **SYSTEMTIME**.

From there you simply then convert your UTC **SYSTEMTIME** to **FILETIME** (**SystemTimeToFileTime()** in **SysUtils**).

The callback proc is a first class proc, not a form method, and must conform to the expected callback signature.

The callback proc will be called in a separate thread so your callback implementation to start the countdown timer must be thread safe.  The simplest way to achieve this is to exploit message queues and simply send (or post) a message to the form which in turn responds by starting the countdown timer.  To ensure the right window handle is used, this can be passed to the callback proc.  Since a HWND fits in a pointer you can just pass the HWND in the pointer directly, by typecasting.

Your callback proc will look something like this:

```
procedure TimerCallbackProc(aData: Pointer; aTimerLo, aTimerHi: DWORD);
begin
  PostMessage(HWND(aData), MM_STARTCOUNTDOWNTIMER, 0, 0);
end;
```

Where **MM_STARTCOUNTDOWNTIMER** is a private, **WM_USER** based message that the form handles to start the countdown timer:

**NOTE:**  Your form must cancel the callback timer when it is closed, either before the timer has 'fired' or as a result of it.

Putting all of that together, you should end up with something like:

```
const
  MM_STARTCOUNTDOWNTIMER = WM_USER + 1;


type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
    fCloseCountdownTimer: TTimer;
    fCloseTimer: HANDLE;
    ..
    procedure MMStartCountdownTimer(var aMessage: TMessage); message MM_STARTCOUNTDOWNTIMER;
  end;


  procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
  begin
     ..

     ..
     fCloseTimer := CreateWaitableTimer( .. );
     SetWaitableTimer( fCloseTimer, dueTime, 0, TimerCallbackproc, Pointer(Handle), TRUE );
  end;


  procedure TMyForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject); 
  begin
    CancelWaitableTimer( fCloseTimer );
  end;


  procedure TMyForm.MMStartCountdownTimer(var aMessage: TMessage); 
  begin
    fCloseCountdownTimer.Enabled := TRUE;
  end;
```

NOTE: The final **TRUE** parameter in the call to **SetWaitableTimer()** in the code above ensures that if the system is suspended at time that the timer fires, then the system will wake in order to process the timer.  If this is not what you want, then simply pass FALSE, and the timer will not wake a sleeping system (but your form will not now close automatically if the due time has been and gone while the system was asleep).

For further and more specific details, I suggest you refer to the [Waitable Timer API documentation from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/windows/desktop/ms687012(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I know this is a more solid solution, but I am under the impression this is quite complex for the OP to understand and implement.

Comment: I tried to provide enough detail to guide them.  If it is a bit of a stretch for the OP, this could be a good thing - after all, stretching ourselves is an effective way of learning.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You only need one timer. This timer will compare the current time with the destination time(s), determining the number of seconds between each time. If it's within a certain range, it shows and sets the progress bar. Otherwise, it hides it.

Here's a demo application below. Save both these files and add them to your project. When you start it, wait 30 seconds for it to start counting down (Time is set to 2 minutes from now, and countdown lasts 90 seconds before close).

***Unit1.dfm***

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 310
  Top = 121
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 188
  ClientWidth = 562
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 41
    Top = 28
    Width = 44
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Close At:'
  end
  object Label2: TLabel
    Left = 216
    Top = 28
    Width = 44
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Warning:'
  end
  object lblSecondsLeft: TLabel
    Left = 41
    Top = 143
    Width = 62
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Seconds Left'
    Visible = False
  end
  object ProgressBar1: TProgressBar
    Left = 41
    Top = 120
    Width = 448
    Height = 17
    TabOrder = 0
    Visible = False
  end
  object dtTime: TDateTimePicker
    Left = 96
    Top = 24
    Width = 97
    Height = 21
    Date = 41893.905071574070000000
    Time = 41893.905071574070000000
    Kind = dtkTime
    TabOrder = 1
  end
  object BitBtn1: TBitBtn
    Left = 392
    Top = 25
    Width = 97
    Height = 21
    Caption = 'Save'
    TabOrder = 2
    OnClick = BitBtn1Click
  end
  object txtWarning: TEdit
    Left = 272
    Top = 25
    Width = 97
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 3
    Text = '90'
  end
  object Timer1: TTimer
    OnTimer = Timer1Timer
    Left = 360
    Top = 72
  end
end
```

***Unit1.pas***

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Buttons, Vcl.ComCtrls,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ProgressBar1: TProgressBar;
    dtTime: TDateTimePicker;
    BitBtn1: TBitBtn;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    txtWarning: TEdit;
    lblSecondsLeft: TLabel;
    procedure BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private

  public
    CloseTime: TDateTime;
    SecondsToClose: Integer;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  DateUtils;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled:= False;
  CloseTime:= dtTime.Time;
  SecondsToClose:= StrToIntDef(txtWarning.Text, 90);
  txtWarning.Text:= IntToStr(SecondsToClose); //sanity check
  ProgressBar1.Max:= SecondsToClose;
  Timer1.Enabled:= True;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  dtTime.DateTime:= DateUtils.IncMinute(Now, 2);
  BitBtn1Click(nil);
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  T: TDateTime;
  Secs: Integer;
begin
  T:= Now;
  Secs:= SecondsBetween(T, CloseTime);
  if T >= CloseTime then begin
    if Secs < 30 then //Only if within 30 seconds of close time
      Close;
  end else
  if (Secs <= SecondsToClose)  then begin
    ProgressBar1.Visible:= True;
    lblSecondsLeft.Visible:= True;
    ProgressBar1.Position:= ProgressBar1.Max - Secs;
    lblSecondsLeft.Caption:= IntToStr(Secs)+' Seconds Before Close';
  end else begin
    ProgressBar1.Visible:= False;
    lblSecondsLeft.Visible:= False;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Consider what happens when the system changes time for daylight saving. Or when the user changes the date time manually. You should not rely on system time.

Answer (score 0):

I think a neat way would be putting the required times in the database and have the table check the times:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
if  FDTable1.Locate('Time',StrToTime(FormatDateTime('hh:mm:ss',now))]),[])   then
begin
....
```

Comment: I don't understand how this answers your question.

Comment: Timer checks with table if desired time exists in database.if current time equals desired time then triggers the progress bar.

Comment: That's identifying the time you want to close. That's a different question. Your question above is asking about a progress bar counting down.

Comment: the question is about closing form on certain hours. progress bar is just to emphasize the countdown to closing.

Comment: Closing the form at a certain time is easy, showing a progress bar is a little more involved. I'm working on an answer now...

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question you asked. You'll also miss triggers then the machine is sleeping

Comment: Yes, a database can store times, but that's not what you asked.  Two other readers have gone to obvious trouble to write useful answers to your q.  Your "answer" seems to imply they needn't have bothered.