# Understanding waitable timers

Tags: delphi, timer, windows-7

There's something I don't understand about waitable timers.  I searched online and read specs on MSDN plus whatever I could find on stackoverflow (such as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798341/close-the-form-on-certain-hours-of-the-day/25800052#25800052)) but my timers fire almost immediately after the PC is suspended.

To focus on the problem I wrote a small test app using XE5 (64-bit) in Windows 7 and tried to duplicate the project found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49798/Wake-the-PC-from-standby-or-hibernation

I thought the problem was the way I derive time but I can't seem to find the problem.

The test app looks like this (very simple):

[image]

I declare the thread type as follows

```
type
   TWakeupThread    = class(TThread)
   private
     FTime:         LARGE_INTEGER;
  protected
     procedure      Execute; override;
  public
     constructor    Create(Time: LARGE_INTEGER);
  end;
```

...

```
constructor TWakeupThread.Create(Time: LARGE_INTEGER);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FreeOnTerminate:=True;
  FTime:=Time;
end;


procedure TWakeupThread.Execute;
var
   hTimer:     THandle;
begin
  // Create a waitable timer.
  hTimer:=CreateWaitableTimer(nil, True, 'WakeupThread');
  if (hTimer <> 0) then
  begin
     //CancelWaitableTimer(hTimer);
     if (SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, FTime.QuadPart, 0, nil, nil, True)) then
     begin
        WaitForSingleObject(hTimer, INFINITE);
     end;
     CloseHandle(hTimer);
  end;
end;
```

Now when the "Set timer" button is clicked I calculate file time this way and create the thread.

```
procedure TForm1.btnSetTimerClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   iUTCTime : LARGE_INTEGER;
   SysTime  : _SystemTime;
   FTime    : _FileTime;
   hHandle  : THandle;
   dt       : TDateTime;
begin
   ReplaceDate(dt,uiDate.DateTime);
   ReplaceTime(dt,uiTime.DateTime);
   DateTimeToSystemTime(dt, SysTime);
   SystemTimeToFileTime(SysTime, FTime);
   LocalFileTimeToFileTime(FTime, FTime);
   iUTCTime.LowPart := FTime.dwLowDateTime;
   iUTCTime.HighPart := FTime.dwHighDateTime;
   TWakeupThread.Create(iUTCTime);
end;
```

This does not work.  The timer seems to fire less then 2 minutes after the system enters suspend mode regardless of the amount of time selected.  Any pointers as to what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Found this interesting command line tool that let's us inspect the waitable timers.  From command you can "see" the state of your waitable timers by typing:

```
powercfg -waketimers
```

I can use this to confirm that my timers are being set properly.  I can also use this to confirm that my timers are still running when the PCs prematurely wake-up.

Using the same tool you can get a list of devices that are able to wake from hibernation (mouse, keyboard, network in my case):

```
powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
```

On all systems tested, the command "powercfg -lastwake" returns the following which I do not know how to decipher:

```
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
   Wake Source Count - 0
```

I enabled both sleep and hibernate in Windows and both will wake up after a few seconds.  There's no keyboard / mouse activity and we don't have devices sending WOL (wake-on-lan) requests to these PCs.

I'm wondering if there's something special I need to do when calling SetSuspendState; here's my code:

```
function SetSuspendState(Hibernate, ForceCritical, DisableWakeEvent: Boolean): Boolean;
//Hibernate = False : system suspends
//Hibernate = True : system hibernates
begin
  if not Assigned(_SetSuspendState) then
     @_SetSuspendState := LinkAPI('POWRPROF.dll', 'SetSuspendState');
  if Assigned(_SetSuspendState) then
     Result := _SetSuspendState(Hibernate, ForceCritical, DisableWakeEvent)
  else
     Result := False;
end;
function LinkAPI(const module, functionname: string): Pointer;
var
   hLib: HMODULE;
begin
     hLib := GetModuleHandle(PChar(module));
     if hLib =0 then
        hLib := LoadLibrary(PChar(module));
     if hLib <> 0 then
        Result := getProcAddress(hLib, PChar(functionname))
     else
        Result := nil;
end;
procedure TForm1.btnSuspendClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
     SetSuspendState(True, False, False);
end;
```

Comment: Are you sure the timer is waking the system. What happens if you suspend the system without setting the timer. You also don't check for errors as the docs specify. Look for ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED when SetWaitableTimer succeeds.

Comment: There's a command line tool called powercfg that lets you query the  wakable timers and get some info. From command prompt "powercfg -devicequery wake_armed" shows which devices can wake the PC.  I have 5 systems; only one wakes up by itself (without a timer).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks for the help.  So I call GetLastError before WaitForSingleObject and compare result to ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED. Is this the right way ?  In my tests, GetLastError does not return ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED.

Comment: @KenWhite tried the suggestion but it did not make a difference only that the app generates errors now when I close it...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I think you are correct; something else is waking up the pc.  Through process of elimination with the key/mouse/net I found that the pc wakes up immediately only when the network cable is connected.  Tried two switches=same behavior.  With the network cable unplugged the code behave as expected.  Curious thing is that I observe this on 5 pcs and only two share a common platform.  Need to look at the drivers/configuration of the network adapters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was **not** related to delphi or the code in any way.  The problem was created by a Windows 7 *feature* that enables more than magic packets when WOL is enabled.  Forcing Windows to only listen for magic packets solved the problem.

MS Link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941145

Thank you to everyone who tried to help and especially to David Heffernan who alluded to the possibility that something else was waking up the PC.